# Why does my latex formula looks different to image?

Tags: symbols

My tex should looks like that:

[image: latex1]

I can only do this:

[image: latex2]

My whole tex code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{article}


\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{polski,enumerate,amsmath,amssymb, multicol}


\begin{document}

$\displaystyle S_k = \sum^{\infty}_{1=1}u_{k,l} (k=1,2,3,\dots)$, mamy $\displaystyle S=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}S_k$, skąd, w myśl $(3)$

(dla $a>0$):
$$
a^{s_{k}}=\prod_{l=1}^{\infty} a^{u_{k, l}} \quad \text { oraz } \quad a^{s}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} a^{s_{k}}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{l=1}^{\infty} a^{u_{k, l}}\right) \text {. }
$$

czyli

%here is my formula I want to fix
$$
\displaystyle a^{\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \sum^{\infty}_{l=1}u_{k,\:l}} = \prod^{\infty}_{k=l} \prod^{\infty}_{l=1} a^{u_{k, l}}
$$
\end{document}
```

And used packages:

```
\usepackage{polski,enumerate,amsmath,amssymb, multicol}
```

I want sum symbols and prod symbols look like the ones in the picture, another problem is that theres big space between equal symbol and my is short in comparison.

Comment: Please provide the missing parts we need to copy and compile: \documentclass, \usepackage, \begin+end document, with your code at the appropriate place, REPRODUCING your problem.

Comment: In addition to what MS-SPO asked, be sure to specify which math font you're using, since you seem to want to get a specific look for math symbols.

Comment: Done, i dont know how to specify font.

Comment: Please be sure to get rid of `\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} `.

Comment: @Mico ok, but why. I need this for my language symbols and this didnt change anything

Comment: cp12850 is a legacy code page. Any modern editor (and latex) should default to Unicode utf-8 so be able to use characters from all languages without changing encoding

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use winshell for my shool lessons and when i delete this my symbols are gone, and this doesnt seems to interfere my math symbols cuz even if i delete this, sum and prod are the same

Comment: `a^{\displaystyle `  do you _really_ want that? Forcing the over-sized summation which is larger than normal text size in a superscript that normally has a small font? Both of your images are very hard to read because of this layout.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I want that, I HAVE TO do same formula as image, so infty should be above sum

Comment: complain to whoever asked for that, other than that it is hard to guess what font you want, your "desired version" looks almost bold but I suspect it is not really bold, just a grainy fuzzy bitmap image, which makes it hard. Perhaps try a  darker times -like font, add `\usepackage{stix2}` or `\usepackage{newtxmath}` (not both at same time) (subscript on the product should be k=1 not k=l I guess)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes theres k=1. first package made sum and prod symbols gone and second package caused error and opened file with .sty extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\limits` rather than `\displaystyle` to use  limits below the summation, displaystyle forces the superscript to be unreasonably large and hard to recognise as a superscript.

I used `stix2` to use a bolder, more robust font.

In the final expression I used a double length = if you really need that. I also fixed the typo: k=1 on the first product, your question has k=l

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

%any code copied from stackexchage is UTF-8 not cp1250
%\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{polski,enumerate,amsmath,amssymb, multicol}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle S_k = \sum^{\infty}_{1=1}u_{k,l} (k=1,2,3,\dots)$, mamy $\displaystyle S=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}S_k$, skąd, w myśl $(3)$

(dla $a>0$):
\[
a^{s_{k}}=\prod_{l=1}^{\infty} a^{u_{k, l}} \quad \text { oraz } \quad a^{s}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} a^{s_{k}}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{l=1}^{\infty} a^{u_{k, l}}\right) \text {. }
\]

czyli

%here is my formula I want to fix
\[
a^{\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=1} \sum\limits^{\infty}_{l=1}u_{k,\:l}} = \prod^{\infty}_{k=1} \prod^{\infty}_{l=1} a^{u_{k, l}}
\]

\[
a^{\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=1} \sum\limits^{\infty}_{l=1}u_{k,\:l}} \!=\joinrel= \prod^{\infty}_{k=1} \prod^{\infty}_{l=1} a^{u_{k, l}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is `1=1` also a typy?

Comment: @hpekristiansen er well at least 1=1 is true!